# Php database handling

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a php page that compare information received by a client with information in a database, but I'm not so good in php and I don't know what I did wrong, I always get response code 500, internal server error.
Here is the code:

```
<?php
/**
 * @var object $payload The payload sent from the client
 */
$payload = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
/**
 * @var object $user_name The username sent by the client
 * @var object $user_name The password sent by the client
 */
$user_name = $payload['username'];
$user_password = $payload['password'];
$response = null;
$responseCode = 200;
$result_row = null;
/**
 * The form representing a positive response
 */
class Response {
    public $accessToken = "";
    public $availableProfiles = "";
    public $selectedProfile = "";
}
/**
 * The form representing a negative response
 */
class negativeResponse {
    public $error = "";
    public $errorMessage = "";
}
/**
 * @var object $db_connection The database connection
 */
$db_connection = null;
try {
    $db_connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=launcher_login;charset=utf8', 'myUser', 'myPass');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    //Catch exception
}

// user can login with his username or his email address.
// if user has not typed a valid email address, we try to identify him with his user_name
if (!filter_var($user_name, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    // database query, getting all the info of the selected user
    $query_user = $this->db_connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = :user_name');
    $query_user->bindValue(':user_name', $user_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_user->execute();
    // get result row (as an object)

    $result_row = $query_user->fetchObject();
// if user has typed a valid email address, we try to identify him with his user_email
} else  {
    // database query, getting all the info of the selected user
    $query_user = $db_connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = :user_email');
    $query_user->bindValue(':user_email', trim($user_name), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_user->execute();
    // get result row (as an object)
    $result_row = $query_user->fetchObject();
}

// if this user not exists
if (!isset($result_row->user_id)) {
    $response = new negativeResponse();
    $response->error = "Credenziali Invalide";
    $response->errorMessage = "Non esiste un account con questa combinazione nome utente/password";
    $responseCode=201;
// if the password isn't correct
} else if (!password_verify($user_password, $result_row->user_password_hash)) {
    $response = new negativeResponse();
    $response->error = "Credenziali Invalide";
    $response->errorMessage = "Non esiste un account con questa combinazione nome utente/password";
    $responseCode=201;
// if the account exists but it isn't activated
} else if ($result_row->user_active != 1) {
    $response = new negativeResponse();
    $response->error = "Account non attivo";
    $response->errorMessage = "Devi attivare l'account! Controlla l'email inserita";
    $responseCode=201;
} else {
    $response = new Response();
    $response->accessToken = hash('md5', $user_name);
    $response->availableProfiles = array(array('id' => hash('md5', $user_name), 'name' => $user_name, 'legacy' => true));
    $response->selectedProfile = array('id' => hash('md5', $user_name), 'name' => $user_name, 'legacy' => true);
}
echo json_encode($response);
http_response_code($responseCode);
```

My table is created with this query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `launcher-login`.`users` (
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'auto incrementing user_id of each user, unique index',
 `user_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user''s name, unique',
 `user_password_hash` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user''s password in salted and hashed format',
 `user_email` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user''s email, unique',
 `user_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'user''s activation status',
 `user_activation_hash` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'user''s email verification hash string',
 `user_password_reset_hash` char(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'user''s password reset code',
 `user_password_reset_timestamp` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'timestamp of the password reset request',
 `user_rememberme_token` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'user''s remember-me cookie token',
 `user_failed_logins` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'user''s failed login attemps',
 `user_last_failed_login` int(10) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'unix timestamp of last failed login attempt',
 `user_registration_datetime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `user_registration_ip` varchar(39) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0.0.0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `user_name` (`user_name`),
 UNIQUE KEY `user_email` (`user_email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='user data';
```

**EDIT: I feel stupid, the error was `$query_user = $this->db_connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = :user_name');`. I was using this outside of a class, now I'm working on the client part, thank you all for help**

Comment: Start by writing the contents of `$payload` out so you know what is being sent to the script. Try `file_put_contents('dump.txt', print_r($payload,true))'` then look at dump.txt, maybe add it to the question

Comment: Could you output the respective error from logs?

Comment: this can be resolved extremely quick by looking at the error log as it'll tell you the exact line your code is blowing up on.

Comment: A few notes as well. 1) http_response_code() needs to come before you output anything to the browser otherwise it will not set the response code correctly. 2) http response code 201 isn't appropriate for invalid credentials, a 401 is appropriate. see this page for response code definitions. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: How can I see the log? In the Chrome Development Tool console I see only GET http://myurl 500 (Internal Server Error)       authenticate.php:1

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost certain the issue is that $db_connection is null since the connection is failing. Based on what you provided your database name should be `launcher-login` instead of `launcher_login` as you've specified in your connection string. As such the following edit should fix your problem.

```
try {
    $db_connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=launcher-login;charset=utf8', 'myUser', 'myPass');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Unable to connect to database'; exit;
}
```

Comment: No, I tried and that's not a db problem, the correct table name is launcher_login and I only wrote it wrong in the creation query I pasted here.